# How to change body background color with if in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm creating a simple iOS app with SwiftUI, and I'd like to change my view's background color when switch toggle change.
[image]

**My code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isOnLight: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $isOnLight) {
                Text("Switch")
                    .font(.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            
            if isOnLight {
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. What you intend is not clear, and you aren't showing your attempt to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to embed your `VStack` inside a `ZStack`, where the back layer is a color that changes every time `isOnLight` changes.

Like this:

```
struct Example: View {
    
    @State private var isOnLight: Bool = false
    @State private var color: Color = .white
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            color
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $isOnLight) {
                    Text("Switch")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onChange(of: isOnLight) { value in
            if value {
                color = .yellow
            } else {
                color = .white
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For background colors you can use the ZStack like this and with one line ifs then decide on the color

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isOnLight: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            isOnLight ? Color.blue : Color.red
            VStack {
                Toggle(isOn: $isOnLight) {
                    Text("Switch")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

To learn about how to use ternary operator in SwiftUI you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzFSOdpxy-o) video

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer smh

Comment: @JPG I think HunterLion's answer was better